# Category image is not getting displayed in top navigation menu after Block override

Tags: magento2, navigation, category-image

Im trying to display the category image in the top navigation,

If I use the following snippet in the core class, images are displayed, but not using my **\app\code\Ibnab\MegaMenu\Block\Html\Topmega.php**

Below is the code i m using to get the category images in the top menu in my overridden class

```
protected function _getHtml2(
    \Magento\Framework\Data\Tree\Node $menuTree,
    $childrenWrapClass,
    $limit,
    $colBrakes = []
) {
  .....
$html .= '<a href="' . $child->getUrl() . '" ' . $outermostClassCode . '><span>';

        // Custom -Use sub category image instead of name if available
        $html .= ($child->getDataByKey('image_url')!='') ? '<img src="' . $child->getDataByKey('image_url') . '">' : '';
        $html .=$child->getDataByKey('name');
        $html .= '</span></a>' . $this->_addSubMenu2(
            $child,
            $childLevel,
            $childrenWrapClass,
            $limit
        ) . '</li>';
        }
        $itemPosition++;
        $counter++;
   .....
```

**\app\code\Ibnab\MegaMenu\etc\di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
      <preference for="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu" type="Ibnab\MegaMenu\Block\Html\Topmega" />
      <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Plugin\Block\Topmenu" type="Ibnab\MegaMenu\Plugin\Block\Topmenu" /> 
   </config>
```

**\app\code\Ibnab\MegaMenu\Block\Html\Topmega.php**

```
<?php

namespace Ibnab\MegaMenu\Block\Html;

use Magento\Framework\DataObject\IdentityInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
use Magento\Framework\Data\TreeFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Tree\Node;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Tree\NodeFactory;
use Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu;
use Magento\Cms\Model\BlockRepository;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;
/**
* Html page top menu block
*/
class Topmega extends Topmenu 
{
/**
 * Cache identities
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $identities = [];

/**
 * Top menu data tree
 *
 * @var \Magento\Framework\Data\Tree\Node
 */
protected $_menu;

/**
 * Core registry
 *
 * @var Registry
 */
protected $registry;
/**
 * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory
 */
protected $categoryFactory;
/**
 * @var \Magento\Cms\Model\Template\FilterProvider
 */
protected $_filterProvider;

/**
 * Store manager
 *
 * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
 */
protected $_storeManager;

/**
 * Block factory
 *
 * @var \Magento\Cms\Model\BlockFactory
 */
protected $_blockFactory;
/**
 * Core registry
 *
 * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
 */
protected $coreRegistry = null;
/**
 * @var \Ibnab\CategoriesUrl\Helper\Data
 */
protected $dataHelper;
/**
 * @param Template\Context $context
 * @param NodeFactory $nodeFactory
 * @param TreeFactory $treeFactory
 * @param array $data
 */
public function __construct(
    Template\Context $context,
    NodeFactory $nodeFactory,
    TreeFactory $treeFactory,
    CategoryFactory $categoryFactory,
    \Magento\Cms\Model\Template\FilterProvider $filterProvider,
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    \Magento\Cms\Model\BlockFactory $blockFactory,
    Registry $registry,
    \Ibnab\MegaMenu\Helper\Data $dataHelper,
    array $data = []
) {
    parent::__construct($context,$nodeFactory,$treeFactory, $data);
    $this->categoryFactory = $categoryFactory;
    $this->_filterProvider = $filterProvider;
    $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
    $this->_blockFactory = $blockFactory;
    $this->coreRegistry = $registry;
    $this->dataHelper = $dataHelper;
    $this->_menu = $this->getMenu();
}
/**
 * Prepare Content HTML
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getBlockHtml($id)
{
    $blockId = $id;
    $html = '';
    if ($blockId) {
        $storeId = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId();
        /** @var \Magento\Cms\Model\Block $block */
        $block = $this->_blockFactory->create();
        $block->setStoreId($storeId)->load($blockId);
        if ($block->isActive()) {
            $html = $this->_filterProvider->getBlockFilter()->setStoreId($storeId)->filter($block->getContent());
        }
    }
    return $html;
}

/**
 * Add sub menu HTML code for current menu item
 *
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Tree\Node $child
 * @param string $childLevel
 * @param string $childrenWrapClass
 * @param int $limit
 * @return string HTML code
 */
protected function _addSubMenu2($child, $childLevel, $childrenWrapClass, $limit)
{

    if($this->dataHelper->allowExtension())
    {
    $html = '';
    if (!$child->hasChildren()) {
        return $html;
    }

    $colStops = null;
    if ($childLevel == 0 && $limit) {
        $colStops = $this->_columnBrake($child->getChildren(), $limit);
    }


    $category = "";
    if ($childLevel == 0) {
    $html .= '<ul>';
    $category = $this->coreRegistry->registry('current_categry_top_level');
    if($category != null)
    {
    if($category->getUseStaticBlock())
    {

      if($category->getUseStaticBlockTop() && $category->getStaticBlockTopValue() != "")
      {
      $html .= '<div class="topstatic" >';
      $html .= $this->getBlockHtml($category->getStaticBlockTopValue());
      $html .= '</div>';
      }
      if($category->getUseStaticBlockLeft() && $category->getStaticBlockLeftValue() != "")
      {
      $html .= '<div class="leftstatic" >';
      $html .= $this->getBlockHtml($category->getStaticBlockLeftValue());
      $html .= '</div>';
      }
    }
      if($category->getUseLabel())
      {
       if($category->getLabelValue() != "" )
        {
          $child->setData('name',$category->getLabelValue());
        }
      }
    }
      if(!$category->getDisabledChildren() && $childLevel == 0)
      {
        $html .= $this->_getHtml2($child, $childrenWrapClass, $limit, $colStops);   //_getHtml() changed to _getHtml2
      }

    if($category != null)
    {
    if($category->getUseStaticBlock())
    {
      if($category->getUseStaticBlockRight() && $category->getStaticBlockRightValue() != "")
      {
      $html .= '<div class="rightstatic" >';
      $html .= $this->getBlockHtml($category->getStaticBlockRightValue());
      $html .= '</div>';
      }

      if($category->getUseStaticBlockBottom() && $category->getStaticBlockBottomValue() != "")
      {
      $html .= '<div class="bottomstatic" >';
      $html .= $this->getBlockHtml($category->getStaticBlockBottomValue());
      $html .= '</div>';
      }

    }
    }
    $html .= '<div class="bottomstatic" ></div>';
     $html .= '</ul>';
    }
    else
    {
        $html .= '<ul>';
        $html .= $this->_getHtml2($child, $childrenWrapClass, $limit, $colStops);  //_getHtml() changed to _getHtml2
        $html .= '</ul>';
     }
    return $html;
    }
    else
    {
     return parent::_addSubMenu($child, $childLevel, $childrenWrapClass, $limit);
    }
}

/**
 * Recursively generates top menu html from data that is specified in $menuTree
 *
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Tree\Node $menuTree
 * @param string $childrenWrapClass
 * @param int $limit
 * @param array $colBrakes
 * @return string
 *
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.NPathComplexity)
 */
protected function _getHtml2(
    \Magento\Framework\Data\Tree\Node $menuTree,
    $childrenWrapClass,
    $limit,
    $colBrakes = []
) {
    if($this->dataHelper->allowExtension())
    {
    $html = '';
    $children = $menuTree->getChildren();
    $parentLevel = $menuTree->getLevel();
    $childLevel = $parentLevel === null ? 0 : $parentLevel + 1;

    $counter = 1;
    $itemPosition = 1;
    $childrenCount = $children->count();

    $parentPositionClass = $menuTree->getPositionClass();
    $itemPositionClassPrefix = $parentPositionClass ? $parentPositionClass . '-' : 'nav-';

    foreach ($children as $child) {
        $child->setLevel($childLevel);
        $child->setIsFirst($counter == 1);
        $child->setIsLast($counter == $childrenCount);
        $child->setPositionClass($itemPositionClassPrefix . $counter);

        $outermostClassCode = '';
        $outermostClass = $menuTree->getOutermostClass();

        if ($childLevel == 0 && $outermostClass) {
            $outermostClassCode = ' class="' . $outermostClass . '" ';
            $child->setClass($outermostClass);
        }
        if ($childLevel == 0) {
         $arrayId = explode('-',$child->_getData('id'));
         $category = null;
         if(isset($arrayId[2]))
         {
             $id = $arrayId[2];
             $category = $this->categoryFactory->create();
             $category->load($id);
             $this->coreRegistry->unregister('current_categry_top_level');
             $this->coreRegistry->register('current_categry_top_level',$category);
          }
        }
        if (count($colBrakes) && $colBrakes[$counter]['colbrake']) {
            $html .= '</ul></li><li><ul>';
        }

        $html .= '<li>';

        if ($childLevel == 0) {
           $name = $child->getName();;
           $category = $this->coreRegistry->registry('current_categry_top_level');
         if($category != null )
         {
           if($category->getUseLabel())
           {
            if($category->getLabelValue() != "" )
             {
              $name = $category->getLabelValue();
             }
             else
             {
              $name = $child->getName();
             }
            }
            else
            {
              $name = $child->getName();
            }
          }
        $html .= '<a href="' . $child->getUrl() . '" ' . $outermostClassCode . '><span>' . $this->escapeHtml(
            $name
        ) . '</span></a>' . $this->_addSubMenu2(
            $child,
            $childLevel,
            $childrenWrapClass,
            $limit
        ) . '</li>';
        }
        else
        {

         /*To display the category image --*/
         $html .= '<a href="' . $child->getUrl() . '" ' . $outermostClassCode . '><span>';
   $html .= $child->getDataByKey('image_url') ? '<img src="' . $child->getDataByKey('image_url') . '">' : '';
        $html .=$child->getDataByKey('name');
        $html .= '</span></a>' . $this->_addSubMenu2(
            $child,
            $childLevel,
            $childrenWrapClass,
            $limit
        ) . '</li>';
        $itemPosition++;
        $counter++;             
    }

    if (count($colBrakes) && $limit) {
        $html = '<li class="column"><ul>' . $html . '</ul></li>';
    }

    return $html;
    }
    else
    {
    return parent::_getHtml(
    $menuTree,
    $childrenWrapClass,
    $limit,
    $colBrakes
    );
    }
}
/**
 * Get top menu html
 *
 * @param string $outermostClass
 * @param string $childrenWrapClass
 * @param int $limit
 * @return string
 */
  public function getHtml($outermostClass = '', $childrenWrapClass = '', $limit = 0)
 {
   if($childrenWrapClass=="mega"){
    $childrenWrapClass = "submenu";
    $this->_eventManager->dispatch(
        'page_block_html_topmenu_gethtml_before',
        ['menu' => $this->_menu, 'block' => $this]
    );

    $this->_menu->setOutermostClass($outermostClass);
    $this->_menu->setChildrenWrapClass($childrenWrapClass);

    $html = $this->_getHtml2($this->_menu, $childrenWrapClass, $limit);

    $transportObject = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject(['html' => $html]);
    $this->_eventManager->dispatch(
        'page_block_html_topmenu_gethtml_after',
        ['menu' => $this->_menu, 'transportObject' => $transportObject]
    );
    $html = $transportObject->getHtml();
    return $html;
   }else
   {
      return parent::getHtml($outermostClass, $childrenWrapClass , $limit); 
   }
 }


 public function allowExtension()
 {
   return $this->dataHelper->allowExtension();
 }
}
```

Comment: Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu is this type of class avilable in your magento 2?

Comment: Yes in magento 2 we have that class in : vendor\magento\module-theme\Block\Html\Topmenu.php

Comment: Any idea @Dhiren where im going wrong, cause my overriden class seems to be called, only issue with the image display

Comment: debug image code, which execute to show category image. I think it not able to get value after override.

Comment: yes when i debug, i get image url value from core class, but the same value im not able to get in my overridden class, where seems to be the problem?

Comment: share the code which is used to get category images in question or ask new question for this.

Comment: Have updated the code which gets the category images @Dhiren, The image_url variable value is not getting captured at all, it is empty... But i get the url value if i try out in core class

Comment: ok found the issue, wrong function was called, i updated the code, its working now, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to get Category Id from the tree node. And then get the Image url.

```
protected function _getHtml2(
    \Magento\Framework\Data\Tree\Node $menuTree,
    $childrenWrapClass,
    $limit,
    $colBrakes = []
) {
```

.....

```
 $objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
  $categoryFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory');

           foreach ($children as $child) {
            $categoryId = substr($child->getId(), -1);  // Get CATEGORY ID
            $category = $categoryFactory->create()->load($categoryId);
```

.....

```
$html .= .'<img src="' . $category->getImageUrl() . ' " width="100px;" height="100px;" />';
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the below code :

In this file 
\Ibnab\MegaMenu\Block\Html\Topmega.php

```
 use \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryRepository;
 class Topmega extends Topmenu 
  {
  protected $_categoryRepository;
    .....
   public function __construct(
    Template\Context $context,
    NodeFactory $nodeFactory,
    TreeFactory $treeFactory,
    CategoryFactory $categoryFactory,
    .....
    ) {
    parent::__construct($context,$nodeFactory,$treeFactory, $data);
    $this->_categoryRepository = $categoryRepository;
    .....
    }
   protected function _addSubMenu2($child, $childLevel,    $childrenWrapClass, $limit)
{

    if($this->dataHelper->allowExtension())
    {
    $html = '';
    if (!$child->hasChildren()) {
        return $html;
    }

    $colStops = null;
    if ($childLevel == 0 && $limit) {
        $colStops = $this->_columnBrake($child->getChildren(), $limit);
    }


    $category = "";
    if ($childLevel == 0) {
    $html .= '<ul>';
    $category = $this->coreRegistry->registry('current_categry_top_level');
    if($category != null)
    {
/** Show top level category image in mega menu **/
        $categoryIdElements = explode('-', $child->getId());        
        $category           = $this->_categoryRepository->get(end($categoryIdElements));
        $html .= ($category->getImageUrl()!='') ? '<img src="' . $category->getImageUrl() . '">' : '';
/** end **/
    if($category->getUseStaticBlock())
    {
  ..........
```

I hope it will working..